# Android banner ribbon using shape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to figure out how I would stack shapes so I can create the following ribbon(Pink/White/Pink/White/Pink part). I will then be using this as a background for my textview.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out using a layer-list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="#FFe5887c" />
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="2dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <size android:width="1dp" android:height="1dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="3dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="#FFe5887c" />
            <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="23dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <size android:width="1dp" android:height="1dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="24dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="#FFe5887c" />
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="2dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```